# How to replace the json data with single quotes

Tags: jquery, json

The Original JSON Data

```
[
  {"year":2008,"value":20,"sales":10},
  {"year":2010,"value":10,"sales":20},
  {"year":2015,"value":5,"sales":30},
  {"year":2020,"value":25,"sales":40},
  {"year":2025,"value":30,"sales":50},
  {"year":2030,"value":40,"sales":60},
  {"year":2035,"value":60,"sales":70}
]
```

I need in this way

```
[
  {"year":"2008","value":20,"sales":10},
  {"year":"2010","value":10,"sales":20},
  {"year":"2015","value":5,"sales":30},
  {"year":"2020","value":25,"sales":40},
  {"year":"2025","value":30,"sales":50},
  {"year":"2030","value":40,"sales":60},
  {"year":"2035","value":60,"sales":70}
]
```

You can see the difference in year Values Replaced with Single Quotes,
after alteration i need the data in JSON Format Only
This is my need, for this i need to convert my year to single quote ,so that the line chart works

```
function Onsuccess(response) {               
            var str1 = JSON.parse(response.d);
            alert(str1);
            Morris.Area({
            element: 'morris-area-chart',
            data: str1,
            xkey: 'year',// here im not getting value of year in line
            ykeys: ['sales'],
            labels: ['value'],
            pointSize: 3,
            fillOpacity: 0,
            pointStrokeColors:['#55ce63', '#009efb', '#2f3d4a'],
            behaveLikeLine: true,
            gridLineColor: '#e0e0e0',
            lineWidth: 3,
            hideHover: 'auto',
            lineColors: ['#55ce63', '#009efb', '#2f3d4a'],
            resize: true
            });
```

Comment: The latter is not valid JSON. Strings must be quoted with double-quotes only. Also, why?

Comment: You can't do that, but you can just use double quotes, that would work easy. Also please provide your current approach please :)

Comment: *"after alteration i need the data in JSON Format Only"* So you don't want single quotes then? Please provide a better explanation of your problem and more context. Is this even a JSON problem or do you just want to convert numbers to strings at runtime?

Comment: @Kirandasvakkil All good, just provide the information we need <3. Do you specificly need single quotes? What did you try so far? Are double quotes an option? Thx

Comment: @StephanT. Double quotes would work, i just tried, Double quotes will do fine <3, how can i convert to double quotes?

Comment: Give @Phil 's approach a try, his is the best solution i think

Comment: @StephanT. Take a look at my code, i have parsed the response to JSON data, so in Json data i need to replace the values in double quotes.

Comment: I did and Phil does exactly that, he parses the String to a Json and then he changes the values of year to string, the only thing you dont need is parsing it back to string

Comment: @FelixKling How about now? Thanks

Comment: @StephanT.  Soo sorry it was the datatype from database converts to string , thank you for the concerns

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am soo Sorry Guys, it was the datatype comming from Database, Thank you to all for the concerns,
The JSON data coming from database in Int and i changed to varchar

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you just want the `year` properties represented as strings, you can cast them by mapping the original array to one with the same data structures only replacing the numeric `year` with `year.toString()`.

```js
const originalJsonData = '[{"year":2008,"value":20,"sales":10},{"year":2010,"value":10,"sales":20},{"year":2015,"value":5,"sales":30},{"year":2020,"value":25,"sales":40},{"year":2025,"value":30,"sales":50},{"year":2030,"value":40,"sales":60},{"year":2035,"value":60,"sales":70}]'

const original = JSON.parse(originalJsonData)
const altered = original.map(o => ({...o, year: o.year.toString()}))
const alteredJsonData = JSON.stringify(altered)

console.info(alteredJsonData)
```

---

If you actually wanted literal single-quotes embedded in the strings, ie

```
{"year": "'2008'", ...
```

then you can change the mapped value to

```js
{...o, year: `'${o.year}'`}
```

Comment: This script does not use single quote for the year.

Comment: @pitaridis: Pretty sure that's intentional because otherwise the result is not valid JSON.

Comment: @pitaridis I'm assuming OP wants a string. Their latter example is not valid JSON so assuming that's the object literal they want, there's zero difference between `"2008"` and `'2008'`. In fact, were you to _stringify_ the example, it would end up the same as my answer

Comment: @pitaridis OP says [_"Double quotes would work"_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50323682/how-to-replace-the-json-data-with-single-quotes#comment87664620_50323682)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a little too simple minded but it does it's deed:

```
var json = {
  "data":[
    {"year":2008,"value":20,"sales":10},
    {"year":2010,"value":10,"sales":20},
    {"year":2015,"value":5,"sales":30},
    {"year":2020,"value":25,"sales":40},
    {"year":2025,"value":30,"sales":50},
    {"year":2030,"value":40,"sales":60},
    {"year":2035,"value":60,"sales":70}
  ]
}
for(var i in json.data) {
    json.data[i].year = json.data[i].year.toString();
}
```

Comment: That would create a string that contains double quotes.

Comment: Thats the point, with normal Json's you can't use single quotes, thats why I asked above if he needs single quotes for a specific reason

Comment: No. In JSON, double quotes mark the beginning an end of a string value. They are not part of the string value itself though. You are creating a string that contains the double quotes as part of the value. I.e. expressed in JSON, you are creating something equivalent to `"\"2008\""` instead of `"2008"`. Do a `console.log(JSON.stringify(json))` to see what I mean.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! <3

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible but if you have to convert it to this format you can constract it yourself.

```js
    var data = [
        { "year": 2008, "value": 20, "sales": 10 },
        { "year": 2010, "value": 10, "sales": 20 },
        { "year": 2015, "value": 5, "sales": 30 },
        { "year": 2020, "value": 25, "sales": 40 },
        { "year": 2025, "value": 30, "sales": 50 },
        { "year": 2030, "value": 40, "sales": 60 },
        { "year": 2035, "value": 60, "sales": 70 }
    ];

    var NewData = "[\n";
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        NewData += "  {\"year\":'" + data[i].year + "',\"value\":" + data[i].value + ",\"sales\":" + data[i].sales + "},\n";
    }
    NewData += "]";
    console.log(NewData);
```

Comment: Sometimes we have to break the rules in order to implement functionalities that the project requires. At the moment that year, value and sales are numbers, this script is not going to cause any problem. It will work and the required json will be generated.

Comment: Well, the result is not valid JSON anyway, so `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: It may not be a valid json but a crazy system may require the json to be imported in this format.

Comment: There's much better ways to build a JSON string, even with newlines and indents, ie `JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2)`. This also adds a trailing comma after the last array item which is not valid JSON